# Redirect to a predefined URL if the previous URL meets a criteria

Tags: php, redirect

We are wanting to redirect to new page on a single page but only if the user's last page was /checkout/.

For example, if the user's last page was /checkout/ then they land on my page, I want them to be redirected to a fresh URL, is this posible with PHP? If so, how is it done? If not PHP, we're open to JS & HTML.

Many Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Hint: Check out `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']`

Comment: what do you mean by last page? last page visit right? and want to redirect on next visit?

Comment: Someone is probably going to mention the HTTP referrer pretty soon ... which you should ignore. Put the information what page the user is currently on into the session, so that you can check it on the next page request.

Comment: Sessions are problematic though if you're opening several tabs/windows at once. Simply *put the information into the URL itself*, period. Each request should be self-contained, that's a basic tenet of HTTP. Make the URL `/somepage?iamcomingfrom=checkout`, or whatever makes sense for you.